# column value for input into database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I create a column in my table that is an input field?

i cant find it anywhere,

I'm looking to have the column for a price that is set at nil/empty, whatever.

Then the user inputs a price which is validated against a reserver price column, if successful it is added to cart.

It's the first part I'm having bad trouble with as my cart is set up already

Comment: I think I don't understand what you want. You want than a user enter a price, for an item, in a html table, in a field. After that, there is a server side validation. If there is no errors, the item added to cart?

Comment: the problem is we are not really sure where to put the fields, we assumed it would be in the product table, we have a make offer column that we want to display a box where where the user can enter a price, which is then validated against the reserve offer price. the reason for having it in the column v a html form is due to having the products in a list form where there is the other atribules side bt side.

Comment: OK... I think Beerlington is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a migration that adds a string field do your database. Check out the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for information on migrations, but it's essentially this:

```
add_column :my_table, :my_field, :string
```

Then it will automatically be cast to a string when retrieved from the database. Once you have that field, you can use the form helpers:

```
<%= form_for @my_model do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :my_field %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorence, im new, so i take it its not possible to have say a products table, in that table a price column, the price column to have a direct user input box indead of a string with a form outside it ? thanks for you help its much much needed for a project soon :)

Comment: we want this user input to write to the database not from etc.

Comment: You don't have to use a form to enter data into the database. If you load up the Rails console, you can interact with the models directly (ie Product.create(:price => 10.2). It doesn't have to be a string, it could be a float, integer, etc, and it would cast it to that type depending on the column type.

Comment: i might try get you more code as you know what your talking about we don't :)

Comment: that would go in your view. Not trying to be a dick, but I would recommend that you stop going down the road you are and take some time to learn Rails. There are some really great resources (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and if you invest some time up front, you'll be doing yourself a huge favor.

Comment: thanks im just stuying it in college and just started so ill be a while before im there yet!! have  a project due and im in a hurry to get it finished! :)

Comment: ah, I remember those days. I hope you enjoy it enough to continue after you finish the course.

Comment: sorry to keepy asking quesitons but im really stuck, say i have my reserve price, to simplify it. how would you describe what i am trying to do? i was thinking orignally having the 2 colums and comparing the prices for validation but i think now if i just have a reserver price coloumn and on its own with a form that is validated against it. where would i put the input box? so a user can type in an ammount to validate againts the reserve price? thanks again your a star!

Comment: Unfortunately Stackoverflow is a terrible forum for these types of discussions. I'd suggest opening another question and try to clearly articulate what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks all the same, your right! but at least there is some decent people on it like you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use text_field like this : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag.

Comment: is this for it to be done when the table is added or is this just for the form after the table is added?

Comment: it is for the end result of entering a number into the database so it can be validated against a another column, we were trying to see do we have to have a form, as in the table we have products, description, brand, RRP, your offer, and hidden is reserver price. those colums display on the page with the stuff seeded in, we want to be able to have a colum that is an user input box for a number with a submit button which then sends the data to be validated againts the reserver price. many thanks