# Validate user input against numeric column and send to cart if true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i asked questions in this [column value for input into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565420/column-value-for-input-into-database)
but still dont get it!
i have a make offer project where i am trying to make a user see a make offer input box on this page.

the user inputs the the form with a number which is then validated against a column in the database called reserve price

here is the validation i have its still not finished, Im trying to figure out what i need to do to finish this for tommrow, i dont know how to put it all together.

```
class Reserve_price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :line_item

  validate :ensure_meets_reserve_price

  private
  def ensure_meets_reserve_price
    if amount < self.line_item.reserve_price
      errors.add(:amount, "does not meet reserve price")
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This is not validation, this is a model. Did you read the guide (link was posted in one of the answers to previous question)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is bad form to have an underscore in a Model name in Rails (though it is perfectly valid Ruby)